# Angularjs directive - exportTable not defined

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I've got small  problem about attaching directive to my module. Let's see:

I've got controller.js:

```
var app = angular.module("app", []);

app.controller('someCtrl', function($scope) {

 $scope.exportAction = function(){
       switch($scope.export_action){
           case 'pdf': $scope.$broadcast('export-pdf', {});
                       break;
           case 'excel': $scope.$broadcast('export-excel', {});
                       break;
           case 'doc': $scope.$broadcast('export-doc', {});
                       break;
           default: console.log('no event caught');
        }
     }

 });
```

and when i want to attach below this directive:

```
 app.directive('exportTable', function() {
 var exportTable = function(){

 var link = function($scope, elm, attr){

 $scope.$on("export-pdf", function(e, d){
       elm.tableExport({type:'pdf', escape:'false'});
  });

 $scope.$on("export-excel", function(e, d){
        elm.tableExport({type:'excel', escape:false});
  });

 $scope.$on("export-doc", function(e, d){
      elm.tableExport({type: 'doc', escape:false});
  });

 }

 return {
   restrict: 'C',
   link: link
    }
  }
});
```

I've got "error: directive is undefined". How I have to attach this?

Comment: what do you mean 'when i want to attach below this directive:' ?

Comment: I mean I want to paste this directive code to my .js file, below controller :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just copied your code  and I don't see any issue with it.

```
var app = angular.module("app", []);
app.controller('someCtrl', function ($scope) {
    $scope.exportAction = function(){
        switch($scope.export_action){
            case 'pdf': $scope.$broadcast('export-pdf', {});
                break;
            case 'excel': $scope.$broadcast('export-excel', {});
                break;
            case 'doc': $scope.$broadcast('export-doc', {});
                break;
            default: console.log('no event caught');
        }
    }

}).directive('exportTable', function() {
    var exportTable = function(){

        var link = function($scope, elm, attr){

            $scope.$on("export-pdf", function(e, d){
                elm.tableExport({type:'pdf', escape:'false'});
            });

            $scope.$on("export-excel", function(e, d){
                elm.tableExport({type:'excel', escape:false});
            });

            $scope.$on("export-doc", function(e, d){
                elm.tableExport({type: 'doc', escape:false});
            });

        }

        return {
            restrict: 'C',
            link: link
        }
    }
});
```